How to get estimate and standard error on same row in R modelsummary library?
I would like to use modelsummary to create a regression table in R. The default regression table produced by modelsummary contains the coefficient estimate and the standard errors on different rows, but I'd like them to be on the same row.
I know that stargazer has a single.row = T option. Is there an equivalent for  modelsummary? I am unable to simply use stargazer because it is not compatible with my regression object (which is a fixest object).
I have tried changing the estimate and statistic options within the modelsummary function but haven't had any luck.

Use the shape argument, as documented on the website here:
https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary.html#shape
And in the manual:
?modelsummary

It might look something like this:
modelsummary(models, shape = term ~ model + statistic)


Thanks for your response! My initial thought was to try to get the coefficient estimate and the standard error on the same row in the same column, but putting them in separate columns works too. Thanks!

You can use estimate="{estimate} ({std.error})" as a "glue" string. This is documented in estimate
